# Partitioning datasets and get the dynamic averages of rows with the same ID(objects in this case)

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a large dataset with thousands of rows though fewer columns, i have ordered them by row values so that each of the 'objects' are grouped together, just like the dataset in Table1 below:

```
#Table1 :

data = [['ALFA', 351740.00, 0.31, 0.22, 0.44, 0.19, 0.05], 
        ['ALFA', 401740.00, 0.43, 0.26, 0.23, 0.16, 0.09], 
        ['ALFA', 892350.00, 0.58, 0.24, 0.05, 0.07, 0.4], 
        ['Bravo', 511830.00, 0.52, 0.16, 0.08, 0.26, 0], 
        ['Charlie', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.14, 0.37, 0.06], 
        ['Charlie', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.27, 0.2, 0.01], 
        ['Charlie', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.29, 0.11, 0.04], 
        ['Charlie', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.27, 0.2, 0.01], 
        ['Charlie', 401740.00, 0.43, 0.26, 0.14, 0.37, 0.06], 
        ['Charlie', 511830.00, 0.52, 0.16, 0.13, 0.22, 0.01], 
        ['Delta', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.34, 0.3, 0], 
        ['Delta', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0, 0.28, 0], 
        ['Delta', 351740.00, 0.31, 0.22, 0.44, 0.19, 0.05], 
        ['Echo', 892350.00, 0.58, 0.24, 0.23, 0.16, 0.09], 
        ['Echo', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.05, 0.07, 0.4], 
        ['Echo', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.08, 0.26, 0], 
        ['Echo', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.14, 0.37, 0.06], 
        ['Foxtrot', 401740.00, 0.43, 0.26, 0.27, 0.2, 0.01], 
        ['Foxtrot', 511830.00, 0.52, 0.16, 0.29, 0.11, 0.04], 
        ['Golf', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.27, 0.2, 0.01], 
        ['Golf', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.14, 0.37, 0.06], 
        ['Golf', 351740.00, 0.31, 0.22, 0.13, 0.22, 0.01], 
        ['Hotel', 892350.00, 0.58, 0.24, 0.34, 0.3, 0], 
        ['Hotel', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0, 0.28, 0], 
        ['Hotel', 590030.00, 0.75, 0.2, 0.29, 0.11, 0.04]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Objects', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6'])

df
```

However i would like to write a query to go through the dataset, partition the data by these objects and get only the averages for all the columns (for each object) in a separate table much like the Table2 below:

```
#Table2: 

data2 = [['ALFA', 548610.00, 0.44, 0.24, 0.24, 0.14, 0.18], 
        ['Bravo', 511830.00, 0.52, 0.16, 0.08, 0.26, 0], 
        ['Charlie', 545615.00, 0.66, 0.20, 0.21, 0.25, 0.03], 
        ['Delta', 510600.00, 0.60, 0.21, 0.26, 0.26, 0.02], 
        ['Echo', 665610.00, 0.71, 0.21, 0.13, 0.22, 0.14], 
        ['Foxtrot', 456785.00, 0.48, 0.21, 0.28, 0.16, 0.03], 
        ['Golf', 510600.00, 0.60, 0.21, 0.18, 0.26, 0.03], 
        ['Hotel', 690803.33, 0.69, 0.21, 0.21, 0.23, 0.01]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Objects', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6'])

df2
```

Please note that the number of the objects vary across the dataset so the query should be able to count the number of objects and use that number to get the average of all the columns for each object and then present all these values in a new table (much Like what partition windows function does).

For instance note that the '548610.00' alues in *Table2* for *ALFA(column1)* is merely an addition of *Column1* values of *ALFA* in *Table1* (351740.00 + 401740.00 + 401740.00) and divide by the count of *ALFA* being '3'

Comment: There is missing the question in your question.

Comment: There is no question at all.

Comment: I am seeking how to get the 'mean' values of all columns for similar 'objects' in SQL, eg the mean values of 'ALFA' across all the columns. The resulting table would have only these mean values for all the 'objects'. i have got a solution to a similar challenge for python, but i was wondering if this can be done in SQL and how can it be done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple avg() function should answer your question

```
SELECT Objects, 
       AVG(Column1),
       AVG(Column2),
       AVG(Column3),
       AVG(Column4),
       AVG(Column5),
       AVG(Column6)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY Objects
```

[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=47e4c224f012150473cc799b3927acfc)